# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm trying to instantiate instances of a User class in user.py based on the number of command-line arguments passed to a python program. I'm getting `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)`. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, argparse
from user import User

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Parse args
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Batch insert")
  parser.add_argument('-d','--dbfilepath', dest='dbfilepath', help='Absolute path and filename of the sqlite database file', required=False, default='/usr/local/foo/bar.sqlite')
  parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose', dest='verbose', help='Verbose output', required=False, action='store_true')
  parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='comma-delimited list of username password pairs', required=True, type=str)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  my_list = [str(item) for item in args.list.split(',')]
  # Only continue if we have even number of items in the un/pw list
  if len(my_list) % 2 == 0:
    count = 0
    u = User(args.dbfilepath, args.verbose)
    while (count < len(my_list)):
      u.create(my_list[count], my_list[count+1])
      count = count + 1
```

file user.py:

```
class User:

  def __init__(self, dbfilepath, verbose=False):
    self._verbose = verbose

    # Open DB and get cursor
    self._con = sqlite3.connect(dbfilepath)
    self._cursor = self._con.cursor()
```

Execution:

```
./batch-insert.py -d /tmp/sql.sqlite -v --list stinky,cat

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create-users-batch.py", line 15, in <module>
    u = User(args.dbfilepath, args.verbose)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Python is this?  Just out of curiosity, what happens if you change the line `class User:` to `class User(object):`?

Comment: If you do `help(user)`, do you get help for the object you are expecting to?  This seems quite strange with the code you've provided ... (also note, python2.x has a builtin `user` module, but it doesn't have a `User` class in it, so it's unlikely that you're accidentally importing that . . .)

Comment: The problem is not in the code you've shown us.  Are you sure that `batch-insert.py` and `user.py` are in the same directory?  Are you sure you saved your last changes to `user.py`?

Comment: Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:28:27) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2

Comment: @dg99: nothing happens when i do that; same error.

Comment: @jgritty, yes they are in the same directory.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include more of file `user.py`?  Also, what happens if you change line 3 to read `import user` and change the beginning of line 16 to read `u = user.User(args...)`?